# mysql date to php

Tags: php, date, formatting, format

I have a date field in mysql that contains numbers like 2455419.  Any idea what format this is and how to convert to php/human eadable form?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be Unix Timestamp. You can convert it to human readable form by using date() function of PHP.

Comment: Or you could use `strftime`. you could also convert it with a conversion function in your actual query with similar functions in mysql.